# 自分のグローバルIPアドレスを調べるコマンドは？

Tags: linux

ブラウザなどを使わずコマンドラインだけで自分が接続に使用したグローバルIPアドレスを調べるコマンドはないんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

```
$ curl inet-ip.info/ip
116.64.92.65
```

これで調べられます

JSON 形式はこちら

```
$ curl inet-ip.info/json
{"IP":"116.64.92.65","Hostname":"[116-64-92-65.rev.home.ne.jp.]","CountryCode":"JP","CountryName":"Japan","Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"],"AcceptEncoding":["gzip, deflate, sdch"],"AcceptLanguage":["en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6"],"UserAgent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36"],"Via":["1.1 vegur"],"XForwardedFor":["116.64.92.65"],"XForwardedPort":["80"],"XForwardedProto":["http"],"RequestURI":"/"}
```

Answer (score 2):

[httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/) はIPアドレスを調べる以外にも色々なHTTPレスポンスを確認することができるのでオススメです。

```
$ curl httpbin.org/ip
```

また、DNSから現在のIPアドレスを調べる方法もあるようです（[参考](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11071/get-your-current-public-ip)）

```
$ dig o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com txt +short
$ dig myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com +short
```